# Can't find files that are taking up a lot of storage on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I've attached the screenshot of my Google Drive Storage report and it tells my my google Drive is taking up 38 GB. For teh life of me, I cannot find the files that are taking up so much space. I have:
1) emptied my trash
2) looked through every folder. The largest file I can find is a measly 15 mb. 
3) I've looked through the folders that have been shared with me and there is nothing significant.

Does anyone have any tips for looking at the file storage of google drive? I'm working on a Mac OS 10.15.4.

Thank you.

[image: my google drive screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. It takes Google 24 hours to update their storage reports after deleting files. I had to empty the trash.